# trying to create a query when greater and less than inside the mysql table php

Tags: php, mysql

Look at my table below. When I have a value and cat, I want to check the id. If I have cat `a` and value `3`, then I will get id `1`, but if I get cat `a` and value `1`, then return false, because value `1` is not greater than `2`. The problem is that the greater sign is inside the table. I cannot figure a way to do it on mysql query, help please. I can alter the table value structure if need.

```
table 
id     cat       value
1       a      greater than 2
2       b       less than 2
3       c       less than 2
4       d      greater than 5

$val = 3;
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE value=$val and cat = a
```

Comment: you can't "execute" values inside a field. you'd have to write an ugly mess of case statements. are you SURE this is the only way to design this system?

Comment: I can alter the table value structure if need. But still, how should my table like, because I need to store the data that this id is less than 2, and that id is greater than 5

Comment: As Marc said, this is likely poor design. If you are open to redesign, you are better off with upper and lower bound fields, "greater than X" would be represented by a lower bound of X (and null upper bound, or max int value) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table 
id     cat       lbound       ubound
1       a         2            2147483647  (Assuming signed int)
2       b         -2147483648  2
3       c         -2147483648  2
4       d         5            2147483647

$cat = 'a';
$val = 3;
SELECT id 
FROM my_table 
WHERE cat = $cat
   AND lbound <= $val -- If you use nulls instead of default extreme values,
   AND ubound >= $val -- then these two bounds comparisons will be more complicated
ORDER BY lbound DESC LIMIT 1 -- if overlapping ranges are possible
```

Design-wise I would prefer nulls for default "no bound" values, but expressions using OR's like `AND (lbound IS NULL OR lbound <= $val)`, or functions like `IFNULL(lbound,-2147483648) <= $val` tend to disqualify index use.

Comment: Thanks for your response.